# Parsing a comma-separated "key: value" string

Tags: bash

I have a text file with several blocks with several lines that may look like this:

```
{ key1: value, key2: value,
  key3: value,
  key4: value, key5: value }

{ key1: value, key2: value, key3: value,
  key4: value, key5: value }
```

Given a `key`, how can I get all the corresponding values?
Note that neither the key names nor the values have a fixed length, blocks start and finish with braces and pairs are separated by commas.

My first try was with `grep` and `cut`, but I couldn't get all the keys. I guess that this should be easy with `sed` or `awk`, but their syntax confuses me a lot.

Comment: Are you attempting to parse [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)?

Comment: looks like `json`. ruby/python/perl/... has packages for parsing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk this might be what you're looking for, though I wouldn't use bash (or extra utils) for this...

Comment: No, it is a yaml file. I didn't find a handy tool to parse a large yaml file (actually I got two of them, but they could not read the entire file). Since I only need those fields, I thought bash was a good choice.

Comment: What characters compose the keys and values? Are they placed around doublequotes? Is it possible for keys or values to have commas or colons?

Comment: @konsolebox, keys are not around double quotes and values are just numbers in scientific notation (e.g. 5.22e+1).

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Can they contain spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First solution with grep:

```
grep -o 'key5: [^, }]*' file
```

Shows someting like:

```
key5: value
key5: value
```

To remove the keys:

```
grep -o 'key5: [^, }]*' file | sed 's/^.*: //'

value
value
```

Comment: I realized that when entering `key5`, I get `value }`. How to avoid that brace?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Your values could only contain numbers right? I updated it as well to exclude bracket `}` and space.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if the key and value are on the same line, and if the key is not contained in any value, if values and keys do not contain spaces, commas, or colons:

```
awk -F'[, :]+' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="key3") print $(i+1)}' file
```

or if you want to the key from a variable

```
awk -F'[, :]+' -v key="$key" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i==key) print $(i+1)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `grep`:

```
sed 's|[{},]|\n|g' your-file.txt | grep -Po '(?<=key1:).*$'
```

`sed` reformats the file to have only one pair key-value on each line; then use `grep` with lookbehind to extract only values correpsonding to a specified key.